# Reducing time between starting an MVC web application and viewing the first page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
- IIS Express 10
- Moderately sized MVC web application
- .NET Framework 4.6.1 x64 debug builds
- Newer Core I7 laptop, plenty of ram, SSD drive

Making a small change in one projects .cs file, hit the green arrow to test out the change.  It takes about 8 seconds for the build to finish and Chrome to pop open a new tab. Not bad. But then it takes about ~30 seconds for the first page to show up.

What can be done to reduce that delay?  Would pre-compiled views be the first order improvement here?  What are some of the best current techniques to achieve that?

Comment: 30 seconds for the view to render is problematic. Is that associated with a database call? Are you rendering very large amounts of html to the view? How much is "plenty" of RAM - because plenty to me could mean up to 128 gigs.

Comment: 16gb, at no point does task manager show that ram getting close to being used up and becoming a limiter.  There are some database calls involved, but they should be nearly instantaneous, but I suppose I should go verify that.

Comment: Sounds like this is in debug mode - that's definitely slower. If you press F12 and check the timings, where is the wait? Is there a database call? If you deploy to a web server in a non-debug build is it faster? As is no one can help you based on your information you need to go and account for those 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll investigate a little deeper and report back with more detail.

Comment: It depends on the Database call and how long it takes for the query to return the result, Any js, css file references (if there are too many then its a problem). Or large HTML page.

Comment: Everyone's comments were helpful, I had always assumed the delay was due to some sort innate environment setup time so had not profiled the application_start path, but 14 seconds of it was WURFLManagerBuilder.Build() in our code.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). Correctly set up it will show you where the delay is including the database calls and their duration etc.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Redgate Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and step through the code locally (potentially pointing at the production database if this is a live problem), this tool should be able to tell you where any slow down is.

One of the features is:

> **Jump straight to the slowest activity**
>
> The call tree in the .NET performance profiler shows you data for
>   every method and identifies the most expensive methods, database
>   queries, and web requests

There is a 14 day free trial, which should be enough time to diagnose your problem.